# integrate multi-variate KDE over intervals to approximate probabilities in scipy

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, cumulative-distribution-function, kernel-smoothing, scipy

Background is I would like to work out the probabilities of certain events occurring to do this,

Say I have three intervals:

- First  `(-inf, -1)`
- Second `(-1, 1)`
- Third `(1, inf)`

For a 1-dimensional problem I can simply integrate the *univariate* `kde` to obtain the probabilities of each interval occurring,

$p_{1} = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)\,dx $, where $f(x)$ is my `kde` function and $p_{1}$ is the probability for the first interval.

And I expect $p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1$

For example:

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                    
from scipy import stats, integrate 

nobs = 100                                                                                                                                            

x1 = np.random.normal(size=(nobs,1)).ravel()                                                                                                          
uni_kde_fit = stats.gaussian_kde(x1)

a = -1
b = 1

#Interval 1
In [33]: uni_kde_fit.integrate_box(-np.inf, a)                                                                                                             
Out[33]: 0.17390197525847215
#Interval 2
In [32]: uni_kde_fit.integrate_box(a, b)                                                                                                                      
Out[32]: 0.6939551130870952
#Interval 3
In [34]: uni_kde_fit.integrate_box(b, np.inf)                                                                                                                 
Out[34]: 0.13214291165443273
```

My outputs are the probabilities of each interval, for example `0.1739...` is the probability of the first. **Notably these probabilities sum to 1.**

Unlike the univariate case when I try apply this same approach to a *multivariate* `kde` my probabilities do not sum to 1.

For example my three intervals in a 2-dimensional case:

- First occurs on the interval `(-inf, -1)` for `x1` and `x2`
- Second occurs on the interval `(-1, 1)` for `x1` and for `x2`
- Second occurs on the interval `(1, inf)` for `x1` and for `x2`

```
x1 = np.random.normal(size=(nobs,1)).ravel()                                                                                                                  
x2 = np.random.normal(2, 1, size=(nobs,1)).ravel()
kde_fit = stats.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x1, x2]))
f = lambda x,y: kde_fit((x, y))

#Interval 1
In [38]: integrate.nquad(f, [[-np.inf, a], [-np.inf, a]])[0]                                                                                                 
Out[38]: 2.9034487847548587e-07
# Interval 2
In [40]: integrate.nquad(f, [[a, b], [a, b]])[0]                                                                                                              
Out[40]: 0.07941141762704332
# Interval 3
In [42]: integrate.nquad(f, [[b, np.inf], [b, np.inf]])[0]                                                                                                    
Out[42]: 0.17307772410724515
```

**These probabilities do not sum to 1**, my implementation of [`nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) looks fine. So my intervals need to change to somehow encompass the entire area of the multi-variate `kde`.

For example if I integrate over the entire space I get approx. `1`.

```
In [45]: integrate.nquad(f, [[-np.inf, np.inf], [-np.inf, np.inf]])[0]                                                                                        
Out[45]: 0.9999999999999591
```

Is there a way/method to define 3 non-overlapping intervals to integrate over the multi-variate `kde` to ensure their sum equals 1?

$$ 1 = {\int\int_{D_{1}} g(x, y)\,dx\,dy} + {\int\int_{D_{2}} g(x, y)\,dx\,dy} + {\int\int_{D_{3}} g(x, y)\,dx\,dy}$$ where $g(x,y)$ is my multi-variate `kde` function.

Comment: What would be the point of using three rectangles for the integration??

Comment: Sorry *edited* - it doesn't have to be I'm trying to understand if there's a way to work out non-overlapping intervals in a 2-D space for my `kde` thus when I integrate the sum of these will = 1

Comment: As you point out, integrating over the entire space works.  As a practical matter, you don't have to extend the integral beyond a buffer of the data equal to the radius of the kernel function.

Comment: ah yes that's true, thanks will keep that in mind